How to locate simple-cache model source files in Simics Public release
in the doc-index documentation
in ch5 cache coherence is mentioned.
In the same chapter at section 5.3
There is a mention of a Python program for creating a cache object. I feel this can be used to define the size of the cache.

But the file path to this python file has not been mentioned
It would be a great help if this file can be accessed, modified and then implemented. But in the documentation we aren't able to find the path to this file. How can I find the path to the same? Or if we get the path to the model c file that too would be great.
We are not able to locate the source files for simple-cache model.

If you want to copy the code to your project for building use the --copy-module function of the project-setup script.
For example, on Windows:
PS C:\...\SimicsProject6> .\bin\project-setup.bat --copy-module simple-cache-tool

And the code shows up in modules/simple-cache-tool in your project.  You can then build it using the standard Intel Simics simulator build setups, either with classic Make or new CMake (the latter is recommended for recent versions of the simulator).

Source code for simple-cache-tool is found in the install folder of the Simics Base package. The path is <installation>/src/extensions/simple-cache-tool.
Best regards
Simon #IAmIntel
